# Count occurrences of some value in list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list that looks like this :

```
fruit_list = [
    ['fruit1', ('banana',  '1234'), ('pear', '3456'), ('banana', '4578')],
    ['fruit2', ('apple',  '5474'), ('mango', '7854')],
    ['fruit3', ('Pineapple',  '4534'), ('apple', '5456'), ('apple', '4458')],
]
```

What I would like to know is given a particular fruit and a particular list within that list, if that fruit appears more than once.

Something like `fruit_list[0].count('banana') > 1`, but I don't think that will work because of the tuples.

Comment: Your sample list is  not valid Python syntax; you are missing two `)` parens, at the least.

Comment: Sorry.  I fixed that. Writing from my phone and I missed that

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `sum()` function with a generator expression to count matching tuples:

```
sum(t[0] == 'banana' for t in fruit_list[0]) > 1
```

This works because python booleans (`False` and `True`) are a subclass of `int` and `False` == `0` and `True` == `1`. Summing those gives you the count of matches:

```
>>> fruit_list = [
...     ['fruit1', ('banana',  '1234'), ('pear', '3456'), ('banana', '4578')],
...     ['fruit2', ('apple',  '5474'), ('mango', '7854')],
...     ['fruit3', ('Pineapple',  '4534'), ('apple', '5456'), ('apple', '4458')],
... ]
>>> sum(t[0] == 'banana' for t in fruit_list[0])
2
>>> sum(t[0] == 'banana' for t in fruit_list[0]) > 1
True
```